# Safest way to store bitcoins

Tags: privacy, sell-bitcoins

If i recieve some dirty bitcoins (large amounts ) which is the safest way to store them in an anonymous place and then convert them into dollars? Do i need a TREZOR?

Comment: What do you mean by "dirty bitcoins"?

Answer (score 1):

Tumble into a paper wallet. Then cash out as you need.
https://blockchain.info/wallet/paper-tutorial

Otherwise replace the paper wallet with trezor as you suggested.

As a note, these two options rely more on physical security than your standard wallet. blockchain.info notes: "The paper contains everything needed to spend the coins and must be kept physically secure."